# Simple AVL tree delete is only working sometimes

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, avl-tree

I'm working on an AVL tree. It seems the my remove only works correctly some of the time. I built a tree that looks like this

```
          f
        /   \
       e     j
      /    /   \
     a    h     s
```

by inserting in the order `f e h s j a`. I know that it is working correctly on insert and balancing.

When I remove `a`, or `j`, or `h`, or `s`, or `e`, everything works fine. If I remove `f`, then it replaces `f` with `h`, which is correct, but I lose `j` and `s`.

This is the first function that is called.

```
    void remove(const ItemType& item)
    {
        if(root == NULL)
            return;
        else
        {
            remove(root, item);
        }
    };
```

The first function calls this one to recursively find the correct node.

```
    void remove(Node<ItemType>* & node, const ItemType& item)
    {
        if(item > node->item)
        {
            if (node->rightChild == NULL)
            {
                return; // there is nothing here to remove
            }
            else
            {
                // recurse to next node
                remove(node->rightChild, item);
            }
        }
        else if (item < node->item)
        {
            if (node->leftChild == NULL)
            {
                return; // there is nothing here to remove
            }
            else
            {
                // recurse to next node
                remove(node->leftChild, item);
            }
        }
        else if (node->item == item)
        {
            remove(node);
        }

        if (node != NULL)
            node->updateHeight();
    };
```

This is the last function to be called. This is where the deletion and swaps are done.

```
    void remove(Node<ItemType>* & node)
    {
        if (node->rightChild == NULL && node->leftChild == NULL)
        {
            delete node;
            node = NULL;
        }
        else if (node->rightChild == NULL)
        {
            Node<ItemType>* temp = node;
            node = node->leftChild;
            delete temp;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<ItemType>* & temp = node->rightChild;
            while (temp->leftChild != NULL)
                temp = temp->leftChild;

            node->item = temp->item;
            delete temp;
            temp = NULL;
        }

        if(node != NULL)
            node->initializeHeight();
    };
```

I am wondering if it has something to do with the lines

```
            Node<ItemType>* & temp = node->rightChild;
            while (temp->leftChild != NULL)
                temp = temp->leftChild;

            node->item = temp->item;
            delete temp;
            temp = NULL;
```

and the temp pointer is acting in a behavior I am not familiar with, or if my whole implementation is wrong. I know the missing nodes are out there somewhere because my memory leak shows me those two nodes that go missing are never deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering if it has something to do with the lines

Yes. `Node<ItemType>* & temp = node->rightChild;` says `temp` is an alias for `node->rightChild`. So the `while` loop modifies `node->rightChild` and you lose the handle to the original right child.

Take an ordinary pointer and walk it down the right subtree until you have gotten to the parent of its smallest member. Then get the value of the smallest member to copy it into `node->item`, and delete the parent's left child.

Comment: thanks, that was indeed it. I replaced those lines with `Node<ItemType>* temp = node->rightChild;
   Node<ItemType>* tempParent = node;
   while (temp->leftChild != NULL)
   {
    tempParent = temp;
    temp = temp->leftChild;
   }

   node->item = temp->item;
   tempParent->leftChild = NULL;
   delete temp;`